# htaccess rewriting if statements

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I am working on a twitter/facebook type site for a college class. Somehow they let a professor teach this class with no PHP, CSS, HTML, JavaScript,jQuery, or Ajax knowledge. I have been trying to rewrite my URLs to make them look like twitter. I have gotten all of my user profile pages to rewrite to: www.site.com/username from: www.site.com/profile.php?name=username. However, I also want to rewrite my login page, create account page, etc. Currently they are: www.site.com/login.html , www.site.com/createAccount.html. I want the to rewrite without the html. Here is my .htaccess file currently.

```
    RewriteEngine  On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?name=$1 [L]
```

**Update

I apologize I ended up switching all of my files over to .php. But I am still having some issues. Now, I only want to redirect specific URLs. For example: www.361orc.info/login should internally redirect to www.361.orc.info/login.php . I cannot seem to figure out what is wrong with the following code. It redirects but it does it changes the client URL. I want it to just redirect internally. Here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine  On

#I want this code to change .com/login.php to .com/login but only internally 
#the URL in the client's browser shouldn't change
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-
RewriteRule ^login?$ login.php [L]

#Change the profile pages of users from .com/profile.php?name=user to .com/user
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ /profile.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this

```
# Rewrite User Profiles
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^profile.php$ /%1 [R=301,L]

# Rewrite Login
RewriteRule ^login.html$ /login [R=301,L]

# Rewrite Create Account
RewriteRule ^createAccount.html$ /createAccount [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close, just an external redirection rule that will redirect `.html` files to ones without `.html` extension:

```
RewriteEngine  On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/file.html to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.+?)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+?)/?$ $1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ profile.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```